# getting Target unkown and state ?? for my S4 on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, galaxy

When I connect my S4 to my computer, it shows on Eclipse that the target of my device is unknown and that the state of my phone is "??"

I have tried installing the driver off of the Samsung website and debugging has been enabled on my phone. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You also have to enable "Unknown Sources" in your Security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your security settings and checking the checkbox `Unknown Sources`.

The description is:

> Allow installation of apps from sources other than the Play Store

Comment: If you've done everything in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ee1vyUY8J7E), then no I don't. If that video did help you, please let me know so I can update my answer. Try installing the drivers on your computer again, or different ones. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If your using Windows. Then please install Kies on your Computer and then try.

THIS WORKED FOR ME!